# C# traversing class members to look for a specific condition

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a C# class that gets loaded with a database row (orm)..this object has all the data in it..i need a way to traverse class level members to look for specific condition? the following is the stop-gap I have and There ought to be a better solution..
Is reflection the answer and how? Thanks!

```
public string findCURRRATEValue()
{
    if (!FUNDNO1.Equals("999") &&
        FUNDTYPE1.Equals("F"))
    {
        return "CURRRATE1" + "#" + CURRRATE1;
    }
    else if (!FUNDNO2.Equals("999") &&
        FUNDTYPE2.Equals("F"))
    {
        return "CURRRATE2" + "#" + CURRRATE2;
    }


------------
-------------

    else if (!FUNDNO59.Equals("999") &&
        FUNDTYPE59.Equals("F"))
    {
        return "CURRRATE59" + "#" + CURRRATE59;
    }
    else if (!FUNDNO60.Equals("999") &&
        FUNDTYPE60.Equals("F"))
    {
        return "CURRRATE60" + "#" + CURRRATE60;
    }
    else
    {
        return "CURRRATEX";
    }
}
```

Comment: One might start by normalizing your database and giving your fields more specific data types.

Comment: I think your problem is more related to the modelling than to how retrieve a value. Why do you need 60 fields with the current rate and 60 fields with the type of the fund? I'd rather have a separate table to hold the current rate for each fund...

Comment: This is not the way to work with relational databases. You should store all this data in rows rather than in columns.

Comment: [explicative omitted]! You should really do something about that data structure. I don't think this is the right question to be asking.

Comment: Why does everybody assume OP even has any control over the schema?

Comment: @Gabe, correcting a bad design at a lower level can frequently eliminate later problems.  The fact that the OP didn't say "I know this sucks but I can't change it" implies that there's room for both education and correction.

Comment: @Gabe - If I were assuming that he had control of the data structure, then I would have posted that change as an answer rather than a comment, because then surely it would be the right answer.

Comment: @Charles: Are you suggesting that every poster list everything about their project they *can't* change? Is it perfectly legitimate to suggest they switch to Python because then they don't have to worry about reflection?

Comment: @Jeffrey: OP stated that the data structure comes from an ORM, implying that it's directly tied to the database schema. The only way to change that is to not just alter the database schema, but rewrite every application and report that uses the database.

Comment: @Gabe - Or create a translator that generates well-formed data for all the systems that have to interact with this mess. Only the OP knows what options are available. But anyway, the fact that there might be no options is why that was a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in reflction terms, this is what you can do:

```
var type = this.GetType();
var fundNoProperties = type.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("FUNDNO"));
foreach (var info in fundNoProperties)
{
    string orderNumber = info.Name.Replace("FUNDNO", "");
    var fundTypeInfo = type.GetProperty("FUNDTYPE" + orderNumber);
    if (info.GetValue(this, null).ToString() == "999" &&
        fundTypeInfo.GetValue(this, null).ToString() == "F")
    {
        var currRate = type.GetProperty("CURRATE" + orderNumber);
        return currRate.Name + currRate.GetValue(this, null).ToString();
    }
}
```

Of course, I have to agree with people commenting **this is not** how you design your databases. However, *data mining* tables might look like this (100+ columns, anyone?) or perhaps *old, legacy systems tables* (over which we have little control). Dirty tricks are not such terrible solution then.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said it is a problem with the way the database is designed.  The best solution would be to create a separate table which holds the current rate for each fund (per @Paulo Santos).  However, if you are stuck with this solution (like many of us are), you could use reflection, but reflection is rather slow (see solution by @Achim).  You could also put each variable into a Dictionary and access the rate via a Dictionary.  This way you don't have to duplicate logic, but if you need to add a field its a matter of adding it to the Dictionary.

Yet another way would be to take the DDD approach and isolate DTOs from entities/value objects.  Keep those objects and use them as if they are a DTO rather than a business object.  Then create a Fund object with a Rate property and map the DTO object to the business object.  Ultimately, this would be the beginning of transitioning to a better data structure-- starting at the C# level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to solve this via Reflection. Pseudocode out of my head which should show the idea, but will probably not compile out of the box:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object val = prop.GetValue(this,new object[0]);
    if (...your condition ...) return "xyz" + value;
}
return "last else case";
```